# Where does the formula for the volume of a hemisphere come from?

Tags: volume

Where does the formula for the volume of a hemisphere come from, I have been using this [The formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHkJg.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: See https://www.famousscientists.org/archimedes-makes-his-greatest-discovery/

Comment: The circle centre $(0,0)$ with radius r is $x^2+y^2=r^2$. You want the volume of revolution generated by this curve from $r-h$ to $r$, which is $\pi\int_{r-h}^{r}{(r^2-x^2)dx}$.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm wondering, I have never seen this formula for spheres? What does $h$ mean? Anyway here's a calculation for the Volume of a sphere with radius $R$:

$$
\iiint_{\|\vec{x}\|=R}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z\\
=\int_{\varphi=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi}\int_{r=0}^R\sin(\theta)*r^2\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\varphi\\
=2\pi*\int_{\theta=0}^\pi\sin(\theta)\int_{r=0}^Rr^2\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta\\
=2\pi*\frac{R^3}{3}\int_{\theta=0}^\pi\sin(\theta)=\frac{4\pi R^3}{3}
$$

If we want a hemisphere:
$$
\frac{1}{2}*\frac{4\pi R^3}{3}=\frac{2\pi R^3}{3}
$$

Comment: It is a portion of the sphere of height h I should think. It can be done as a volume of revolution rather than a triple integral.

Comment: @Paul your're right, rotation would've also been possible and thanks for the clarification for the height

Comment: We don't know if the person who asked this question has had Calculus and I don't believe Archimedes used a triple integral to solve this.

Comment: Marked yours as best answer

Comment: Oh i got it know, thank you :D